# Laravel 5 Ignoring field in ::create method

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Can anyone see why `location_id` is being inserted as `NULL` from the below source?

```
$locationObject = Location::find($location);
if (\ResponseHelper::isValid($locationObject)) {
    print_r("location_id: " . $locationObject->id);

    $recipientObject = Recipient::create(
        [
            'firstname'             => $recipientArray['firstname'],
            'lastname'              => $recipientArray['lastname'],
            'dob'                   => $recipientArray['dob'],
            'last_sent'             => null,
            'last_visit'            => null,
            'source'                => $recipientArray['source'],
            'last_attendance'       => null,
            'last_attendance_class' => '',
            'last_interaction'      => null,
            'last_interaction_user' => '',
            'location_id'           => $locationObject->id,
        ]
    );

    print_r($recipientObject);
```

It should be noted that `$locationObject` is valid and the result from the `print_r` is: `location_id: 20`

In PostMan, the result of printing out the object is:

```
    [attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [firstname] => River
        [lastname] => Tam
        [dob] => 1993-04-04
        [last_sent] => 
        [last_visit] => 
        [source] => f151f36183bbe9012a53c4e367ff5a91
        [last_attendance] => 
        [last_attendance_class] => 
        [last_interaction] => 
        [last_interaction_user] => 
        [location_id] => 
        [updated_at] => 2015-08-14 16:55:58
        [created_at] => 2015-08-14 16:55:58
        [id] => 417
    )
```

*In the Model*

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'dob',
    'last_sent',
    'last_visit',
    'source',
    'last_attendance',
    'last_attendance_class',
    'last_interaction',
    'last_interaction_user',
    'location_id',
];
```

*Resulting DB record*

```
| 392 | 2015-08-14 15:16:43 | 2015-08-14 15:16:43 | NULL      | River     | Tam       | 1993-04-04          | NULL       | NULL       | f151f36183bbe9012a53c4e367ff5a91 | NULL            |                       | NULL             |                       |        NULL |
```

(This is for example purposes only, the actual row isn't shown as I have thousands, but the result is the same, all `location_id`'s inserted are `NULL`, so for the purpose of the question this 'demo' will suffice - location_id is at the end, last column.)

**Edit**
I should also note, that I've just tried: `location_id => 20` and this too, does not work.

**Edit 2**
Schema

```
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| created_at            | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at            | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| last_sent             | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| firstname             | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| lastname              | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| dob                   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| deleted_at            | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| last_visit            | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| source                | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| last_attendance       | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| last_attendance_class | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| last_interaction      | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| last_interaction_user | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| location_id           | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Are you overwriting the create or any method in the model? Maybe some events overwriting?

Comment: Nope, no overriding at all :(

Comment: Are you sure the column name in the database is the same? If so try adding `public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        dd(attributes);
    }` in the model and add the output

Comment: Yup, I'm positive the field is named the same. And that particular method returns an empty array.

Comment: Change the method name to create and see the result again. Seems like for some reason the attributes aren't being passed

Comment: But the create method is doing everything else as I'd expect, it's setting every other field, just not location_id, that is always null.

Comment: The result of postman shows nothing was passed except the source. If you overwrote the construct and you saw the empty array that means the array you passed to create was empty. I)m just trying to track at which point something is going wrong

Comment: Apologies, that was my dodgy copy and paste. I've edited after another run, to illustrate. Sorry.

Comment: if the key field in locationObject is location_id, should't you be setting in your create method 'location_id'           => $locationObject->location_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary solution try this:

```
$recipientObject = new Recipient(
    [
        'firstname'             => $recipientArray['firstname'],
        'lastname'              => $recipientArray['lastname'],
        'dob'                   => $recipientArray['dob'],
        'last_sent'             => null,
        'last_visit'            => null,
        'source'                => $recipientArray['source'],
        'last_attendance'       => null,
        'last_attendance_class' => '',
        'last_interaction'      => null,
        'last_interaction_user' => '',
    ]
);
$recipientObject->location_id > $locationObject->id;
recipientObject->save();
```

This should work, but its not a fix for an issue that you are having. If you want me to investigate more, paste the whole Recipient Model